# Compiled-C on a Jazelle Microprocessor

Tags: microcontroller, arm, microprocessor, atmel, java

I found a chip that is perfect for my application (it has all the necessary features) (Atmel SAM9G45) The processor is based on ARM v5TEJ Architecture with Jazelle technology for Java acceleration. In the datasheet it says:

> processor supports the 32-bit ARM and 16-bit THUMB instruction sets, enabling the user to
>   trade off between high performance and high code density. It also supports 8-bit Java instruction set and includes
>   features for efficient execution of Java bytecode, providing a Java performance similar to a JIT (Just-In-Time
>   compilers), for the next generation of Java-powered wireless and embedded devices
>   Blockquote

My question is, I would like to avoid the fees and risk associated with Jazelle. Does this mean I am strictly required to use Jazelle with this chip, or can I still compile C for ARM 32bit and proceed as I would for other 32bit Arm development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Jazelle extensions is optional -- it's another processor mode.